# Pid as erlang maps key?

Tags: erlang

Can Pid be maps key ?

Build maps from #{} syntax, The error says Pid can not be key.

Bug build with maps module, Pid can be key.

```
18> 
18> Pid = self().
<0.39.0>
19> #{Pid => 1}.
* 1: illegal use of variable 'Pid' in map
20> 
20> M1 = maps:from_list([{Pid, 1}]).
#{<0.39.0> => 1}
21> 
21> #{Pid := V} = M1.
* 2: illegal use of variable 'Pid' in map
22>                  
22> maps:get(Pid, M1).
1
```

Comment: You can use `maps:put(Pid, V, M)` when the key is a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for arbitrary keys in map patterns is already available in "Erlang 18 (release candidate 2)".

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 18 [RELEASE CANDIDATE 2] [erts-7.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.0  (abort with ^G)
1> Pid = self().
<0.33.0>
2> #{Pid => 1}.
#{<0.33.0> => 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't come from the usage of pid, but from the usage of a variable as a key in the map definition. It is not yet implemented (and don't know when it could be done).